# Why did I lose access to the Internet on Linux wether using WiFi or Ethernet?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, internet-connection, protonvpn

I use Ubuntu on my laptop for months without any issues. Today I was unable to connect to my WiFi router. All other devices could connect so I figured that it was not an issue with my ISP nor the router.

I tried to connect my laptop using an Ethernet cable but without success.

I finally booted from a USB flash drive that had an Ubuntu image to see if my wireless adapter still worked, and it did.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that a VPN Kill Switch was active (even though my VPN client wasn't running and couldn't be started) by opening a Terminal session and typing:

```
nmcli connection show --active
```

Then I deleted the Kill Switch connections like so (replace the last argument with the name of your kill switch connections) :

```
nmcli connection delete xxxxx-killswitch

nmcli connection delete xxxx-ipv6leak-protection
```

Problem solved.